# jQuery magnific-popup : create a button inside the popup to close the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Hope you can help me. I read and read again the documentation of Magnific Popup, but I'm not good enough with javascript.

**1- I open a popup with this link :**

```
<a href="mysubpage.html" class="pop">OPEN POPUP</a>
```

and this javascript :

```
$('.pop').magnificPopup({ type:'iframe', showCloseBtn : true, closeOnBgClick : true, midClick: true });
```

**2- in my popup, I would like a button 'CLOSE' to close the pop-up.**

I try this but it doesn't worked :

```
<input type="button" value="CLOSE" onclick="magnificPopup.close();" />
<input type="button" value="CLOSE" onclick="$.magnificPopup.close();" />
<input type="button" value="CLOSE" onclick="$('pop').magnificPopup.close();" />
<a href="#" class="mpf-close">CLOSE</a>
<a href="#" onclick="magnificPopup.close();">CLOSE</a>
```

I read I need to place this code :

```
var magnificPopup = $.magnificPopup.instance;
```

But where ? in which page ? with what syntaxe ?

Magnific Popup documentation : [LINK](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html)

Thanks for helping.
Have a good day ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The following will work. Add button (or any other element)

```
<button id="my-custom-close">close</button>
```

... and this javascript

```
$('#my-custom-close').click(function(){
    //This will close popup dialog opened using $.magnificPopup.open()
    $.magnificPopup.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to add a close button, and option to display inside popup. I would not use custom buttons or elements to try to close the popup, it should be included inside the popup once you have these two options set.

```
<a href='#' class='pop'>Open Popup</a>

$('.pop').magnificPopup({ 
  // main options
  showCloseBtn: true,
  closeBtnInside: true,

  gallery: {
    // options for gallery
    enabled: true
  },
  image: {
    // options for image content type
    titleSrc: 'title'
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
So you say I can't use a custom button CLOSE in the popup ? no solution ? I have to use only the close button X included.
But I really need a custom button, I though it was possible.

Comment: You could find the Id or class selector for the button and override styling via css

Comment: I try to play with the "mpf-close" class but It' didn't work.  :-(

Comment: Thanks you're a really good helper. Your example with codepen is helping me, but is there a way to close with a classic button like : < input type='button' value='close' onclick='magnificPopup.close();' >

Comment: Unfortunately No, this functionality is built into the JavaScript file and I wouldn't recommend changing anything in there. Why would you want the classic button, is it text on the button you're after?

Comment: I updated the CodePen, At bottom of JS file it shows you how to add your own markup button. And a piece of code to show you how to detect when user clicks close button.